Why do people have an aversion to practicing speaking foreign languages by themselves?
I can't think of any other skill than speaking a foreign language where people (despite having no non-mental obstacle to doing so) often choose not to practice by themselves.
This doesn't apply to reading, writing, or listening in foreign languages, which people practice by themselves, and realize solo practice is absolutely essential to learning.  This doesn't apply to practicing the guitar, or kung fu, or calculus, or singing, or chess.  (It applies to say, 10-pin bowling, because most people don't have their own bowling alley.)
It's widely accepted that, for a wide range of disciplines, practicing by yourself is absolutely essential, to the point where it's hard to conceive how someone might learn the guitar without practicing solo.
Question: Why do people have an aversion to practicing speaking foreign languages by themselves?
I guess there's some psychological reason why people have a strong aversion to this specific task (speaking a foreign language) when it's performed alone, and not have the same aversion to listening/reading/writing in a foreign language alone, nor learning a musical instrument.

That's your opinion. Listening and repeating is one of the main ways to learn a language... In fact, that's what language labs in schools are all about.

I think that this claim is incorrect, or at least difficult to prove. Practicing alone is a necessary part of learning a language and many language learning methods do rely on such practice - like those age old ones, where one must repeat words or phrases after a recorded native speaker. Such methods may be somewhat out of fashion, in favor of more interactive approaches, but I met some people who actually learned a language this way - usually with outstanding results.
What is difficult about learning a foreign language is that it is a very tedious activity - it may take years before one actually masters a language to working capacity (contrary to a false impression that one gets after an introductory course, where one learns basic phrases and basic grammar, which do make for 80% of all the words and grammar that one needs to know... but which make for only 20% of understanding.) Thus, many people abandon the hard work of everyday exercising... or choose a more fun path of learning language - even if with less perfect results (via reading, watching films, and spending time with native speakers.)

Not old-fashioned, still used. Repeating and recording one's own production and then listening to it is an important step in improving oral skills. Identifying where you go wrong greatly helps to correct  mistakes.

@None I don't doubt the efficacy of this approach -  but what I see offered in modern language schools and books are various "easy" or more entertaining ways of learning languages. As I pointed out in my post, I am sceptical of those.

"Still used". Nowadays schools use specific software on the laptops in the classrooms, but the work is exactly the same as with the old days computer labs. And the  icing on the cake is that the students can continue the work at home on their phones.

@None I have studied with immigrants in four different countries, and I have never seen anyone using records (the people whom I mention in my answer all studied language on their own.) Usually it is repeating after the teacher or listening to songs. At Alliance Française one occasionally listens an adapted text.

Speaking is harder than reading and writing because it requires interaction and it's human nature to feel nervous when we do things we are not good at... I hope I can improve my German-speaking skills faster but it's just not that easy.
